# Oracle SQL Custom sorting

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I want to get sorted rows as **3,4,5,1,2,6,7,8,9** based on status or based on its description,

```
Status Description
1   New
2   Hold
3   Counter-Proposed
4   Partial-Counter-Proposed
5   Confirmed
6   Partial response Accept
7   Respone Accept
8   Response Reject
9   Cancelled
```

I tried with union all by selection only `3,4,5 as a set and 1,2,6,7,8,9  as another set` is there any other easyway instead of multiple sets.Please guide to get solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Status, Description
from Status
order by case when Status in (3,4,5) then 1 else 2 end, Status
```

Comment: Thank you it really helpful ! Could you redirect me to read something with this syntax " order by case when Status in (3,4,5) then 1 else 2 end, Status " ,because i didn't understand the final status why it comes.

Comment: First, all entries with Status in 3,4,5 get 1, thus they sort first, rest of the rows gets 2, so they sort last. Then they get additionally sorted by their real status. So, the returning order is (1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,1),(2,2),(2,6) and so on.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so like temp memory they update the status value while this order by and shows the sorted and original values am I right?

Answer (score 3):

@RedFilters answer works.

However, you could argue that there is a missing column on Status.  You should consider adding a column to Status to represent which "set" the status is in.  Then you can join from your main table to Status, and sort by this new column.

This way, you would not have to remember to update any code if you add an additional status.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, for any custom order:

```
SELECT Status, Description FROM yourtable ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(Status,'3,4,5,1,2,6,7,8,9');
```

Take care: if the Status is not in the list, it will return 0 and therefore will be placed before everything else. If this is not wanted, you could do the following, where every occurence of 0 is replaced by a very large number:

```
SELECT
  Status, Description
FROM 
  yourtable 
ORDER BY 
    CAST(REPLACE(FIND_IN_SET(Status,'3,4,5,1,2,6,7,8,9'),0,4294967295) AS UNSIGNED) ASC;
```